# I need to change source in rdlc report

Tags: c#, winforms, report, rdlc

I made an rdlc report before and now I increased two columns in database table. These two columns are not showing in report, what should I do?

Comment: Add more details for what database approach you're using. In general to update your structure in datasets you should build you project and update you datasource connections through Report Data pane described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627528.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In the Report Data Window,  refresh the Dataset. new fields will be available in the dataset and you may need to add new fields to your report accordingly